# Python multiple dict to df

Tags: python

I have this dictionary that I would like to transform it into a pretty looking df.

```
{'2019-05-21': [{'averageReturn': 0.04691915290638171,
   'returnAmount': 10469.191529063817,
   'terminationDate': '2019-05-21'}],
 '2020-01-15': [{'averageReturn': 0.029923082622105746,
   'returnAmount': 10500.0,
   'terminationDate': '2020-01-15'}]}
```

The problem is I can't pass the dict inside the list into a columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

assuming your dictionary is stored as `k_dict`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({key:item[0] for key, item in k_dict.items()})
```

if you are using python2, `k_dict.items()` becomes `k_dict.iteritems()`

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply

Comment: The chances are you will want to add `.T` to the end to transpose the dataframe (index as dates).